# How to add additional include paths to CMakeSettings.json to get IntelliSense to work?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-2019, intellisense

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 16.7.2 to open a CMake project that uses header files and libs located inside an absolute `C:\dependencies` path. However, that path is never directly referenced in CMakeLists.txt, and is only used in a separate build script that ships with the project and executes successfully. This means that when working on the project within VS, IntelliSense fails to recognize the included headers from `C:\dependencies\lib[A,B,...]`, e.g. `#include <libA/header.h>` will not find the header for autocomplete and similar features.

I am not supposed to modify the CMakeLists.txt directly. Instead, I would like to reference headers from `C:\dependencies` base path in an unversioned [CMakeSettings.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmakesettings-reference?view=vs-2019) file which would hopefully fix the IntelliSense issue. Here's what I tried but it didn't work:

- adding an `include_directories` variable:

> ```
>  "variables": [
>  {
>         "name": "include_directories",
>         "value": "C:/dependencies/libA/include C:/dependencies/libB/include"
>         "type": "PATH"
>  }]
> ```

- adding a CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS variable:

> ```
> "variables": [
> {
>       "name": "CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS",
>       "value": "-I C:/dependencies/libA/include C:/dependencies/libB/include"
> }]
> ```

The path strings themselves are not an issue, e.g. `"C:\dependencies\libA\include"` contains a directory `libA` with the referenced headers.

Any ideas on how to get IntelliSense to recognize the headers successfully?